# JPQL and sub-query in JPQL constructor expressions

Tags: sql, hibernate, jpa, jpql

I have a table ROOT and a table CHILDREN that contains rows related to ROOT.

I'd like to retrieve for each row of ROOT, an object that contains the ROOT object and the number of rows related to the ROOT.id in the CHILDREN table.

This can be achieved quite easily in SQL, but I am wondering how to write that in JPQL

In SQL:

```
SELECT 
    r.*, 
    (SELECT COUNT(c.i_id) 
     FROM 
        children c 
    WHERE 
        c.rootId = r.id)
FROM root r;
```

I tried to rewrite it in JPA but it keeps failing with the following error

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.HibernateException: Errors in named queries: xxx
Caused by: org.hibernate.hql.internal.ast.QuerySyntaxException: Unable to locate 
           appropriate constructor on class RootExtended...
```

Java class:

```
package plop;

public class RootExtended{

    private Root root;

    private Long count;

    public RootExtended(final Root root, final Long count) {
        this.root= root;
        this.count= count;
    }

    // getters and setters to follow
}
```

JPQL:

```
SELECT 
    new plop.RootExtended(r, 
                    (SELECT 
                         count(c.id) 
                     FROM 
                         Child as c 
                     WHERE 
                         c.rootId = r.id
                     )
                    ) 
FROM 
    Root as r
```

Any idea ?

Comment: Please provide more of the stacktrace, as an important part is not showed. Is `RootExtended` an entity?

Comment: Also check if your `RootExtended` class receives a Long as the second parameter.

Comment: @AndreiI no, this is not an entity, I have added the class code

Comment: @GabrielCâmara I tried with dozen of types int, long Integer, Long, Number, Object and so on, but nothing works :(

Comment: I really wanted a bit more of the stacktrace/exception, not of the code.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12271305/jpql-constructor-expression-org-hibernate-hql-ast-querysyntaxexceptiontable-i Check this

Comment: @vels4j my classes root and children are well mapped entities (I have other queries running on those classes)

Comment: So obviously you could do it by `new RootExtended( root, root.getChildrens().size())`

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not allowed to use subqueries in the `SELECT` part in JPA (at least version<=2), as they are restricted to the WHERE and HAVING clauses. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11573591/subquery-in-from-claus-in-jpa2-criteria) for details.

As solution you could make two queries, in the second making the `COUNT()` and loading it in the code to your `ExtendedRoot` instances.

Answer (score 0):

Class :

```
public class RootExtended{

private Root root;

private Long count;

public RootExtended(final Root root, final Long count) {
    this.root= root;
    this.count= count;
}

// getters and setters to follow
}
```

Query :

```
SELECT NEW package.RootExtended ( rt.r, rt.cnt) from ( select r from Root r, 
      (SELECT count(c.id) as cnt FROM Child c  WHERE  c.rootId = r.id ) rt )
```

Comment: I don't think that works, as you are not allowed to use subqueries in the `FROM` clause either. See the same link.

Comment: what kind of magic do you use to make it works... it does not looks like any *QL