# Returning result from 3 tables using JPA criteria

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa-2.0, criteria

I have the following situation:

```
@Entity
public class Period
{
    String Name;
}

@Entity
public class Bill
{
    Period period;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "bill", fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    private List<Entry> entry = new ArrayList<Entry>(0);
}

@Entity
public class Entry
{
    @NotNull
    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "BILL_ID", nullable = false)
    Bill bill;

    String text;

    BigDecimal amount;
}
```

So what I need is to fetch all the data in a single query, either with the root being the `Bill` or the `Entry` using JPA 2.0 criteria (with Hibernate behind). I've read few posts about this problem [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8790852/jpa-lazy-fetch-entities-over-multiple-levels-with-criteria-api) and [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20847847/complex-criteria-query-using-jpa-instead-of-nativequery) and it seems that I can't use subqueries in the result or fetch data two levels deep.

EDIT: To make my problem more clear: When I use `Entry` as root, I can't fetch `Period` and when I use `Bill` as root I can't fetch all other tables in `Entry`. Also I can't use eager fetch because there are other use cases that need those tables.

Are there any other ways to do this?

Thanks!

Comment: It would help if you could also post the HQL or SQL for what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: If you change fetch type to `eager`, it will fetch it, depending on your HQL

Comment: I have different use cases for these table, I can't use `earger` here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To fetch data from association, you use [left join fetch clauses](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.3/manual/en-US/html_single/#queryhql-joins):

```
select distinct b from Bill b 
left join fetch b.period 
left join fetch b.entry
where b...
```

or

```
select distinct e from Entry e 
left join fetch e.bill b 
left join fetch b.period
where e...
```

Regarding Criteria, its [fetch()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/FetchParent.html) method returns a Fetch, which itself has a method fetch() returning a Fetch(), which itself has a method fetch() returning a Fetch, etc. So yes, its supports as many levels you want.

Comment: But how do I fetch `Period` from `Bill` when my root is `Entry`?

Comment: Please read the whole question. Also I need type safe JPA criteria.

Comment: Please try something on your own. Criteria also has fetch. You just need to translate the above queries.

Comment: The point that I'm making above is, that JPA does not seem to have the ability to fetch any deeper than one level, in your example `e.b.period` the `period` attribute is second lvl.

Comment: JPA is not hibernate and your example is not criteria, its HQL.

Comment: It's JPQL. JPQL is part of JPA. Criteria's fetch() method returns a Fetch, which itself has a method [fetch()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/persistence/criteria/FetchParent.html) returning a Fetch(), which itself has a method fetch() returning a Fetch, etc. So yes, its supports as many levels you want.

Comment: That's a great find, thanks. Can you please add last comment info to the answer so I can accept it. regards