# Spring Data JPA subquery in from

Tags: jpa, spring-data, querydsl

Spring DATA JPA support subquery in `from` ?

like

```
select * from (

    select unique_id
    from table_a

) as from_a
inner join table_b
on from_a.unique_id = table_b.unique_id
```

querydsl JPASubquery or Spring DATA criteria impossible?

Comment: Not Possible, check this [You cannot use subquery in FROM clause with JPA 2 Criteria API.](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11574954/4436435)

Answer (score 0):

I think it is noe possible.
in other way. you use JPAExpressions. it will be serching for subquery in query dsl.

But i aleardy user that subQuery that are result only one table.